# JS function in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  **$('.sel1').hide();**

  function show_names(str,val) {
    alert("hello");
    $('.sel1').show();
    $.getJSON('j_process.php?j=1&str='+str+'&val='+val, function (data) {
      var html = '';
      var len = data.length;
      for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
      }
      $('.sel1').append(html);
    });
    return false;
  }
  return false;
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label for="textfield" class="control-label"><?php if($i==$num_row-1) { echo "Save File As"; } else { echo str_replace("_"," ",$row[0]); } ?></label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" <?php if($main_box==$i) { echo 'onkeyup="show_names(this.value, '.$main_box.')"';} ?> id="textfield" name="loc<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php if($i==$num_row-1) { echo "autocomplete='off' onkeyup='searchfile(this.value);' "; }?> value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['loc'.$i])) { echo $_SESSION['loc'.$i]; }?>" maxlength="500" size="50" class="input-xlarge">
  </div>
</div>
```

I put the function outside document read, but the getJSON is not working now.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: It's a function definition, put it outside the `$(document).ready(...)` bit

Comment: whats the value of $main_box ?

Comment: you never defined a global `show_names` method.

Comment: Correct answers below.

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML output, rather than the PHP please? Saves guesswork at our end! :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tallmaris said, you need to move your function definition outside of the `document.ready` function, otherwise your page can't see it.

Example:

```
function foo(){
  function bar(){

  }
  //I can call bar in here.
  bar();
}

function someOtherFunction(){
 //But I can't call bar() here because it's nested within foo.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

show_names() is not defined within the scope of the window in code you have posted. It's only defined within the scope of your document.onReady handler, so it can't be called by the rest of your page.

Answer (score 0):

`show_names` is scoped to your `document.ready` handler. It cannot be called from outside that function as it is not globally scoped.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sel1').hide();
});

function show_names(str,val)
{
    alert("hello");
    $('.sel1').show();
    $.getJSON('j_process.php?j=1&str='+str+'&val='+val, function(data){
        var html = '';
        var len = data.length;
        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
            html += '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $('.sel1').append(html);
    });
return false;
}
```

Try that. Should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sel1').hide();
    return false;
});
function show_names(str,val)
{
    alert("hello");
    $('.sel1').show();
    $.getJSON('j_process.php?j=1&str='+str+'&val='+val, function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
    }
        $('.sel1').append(html);
    });
    return false;
}
```

And make sure to call show_names function